# Nano clone failure, how to prevent it from happening again?

Tags: power, arduino-nano, rgb-led

I'd made an LED driver, and fed both the LEDs and nano clone from 12V. The 12V switched power supply is of dubious quality. The nano itself read a pot, and wrote PWM values on three pins. It has run on-off for 2-3 months. Not long. Now it's dead - my PC does register the serial device on the nano, and the power LED comes on. Apart from that, there's nothing that works.

Before I replace it, I'd like to know if the most likely culprit was my feeding 12V into VIN. Overheating voltage regulator? The LEDs got a bit hot, ~40°, and the nano was in a box with no airflow.

Comment: How did you connect the leds?

Comment: They were connected through 3 2N7000 MOSFETs, they didn't pull power from the nano. I have considered if they exceeded their rated current, but am unsure. IIRC, it's a 10V MOSFET, which I turned on with a 5V signal. The rated current is 200mA max. In any case, would a burnt MOSFET murder my nano? I've heard the act like shorts when they die. Please apply cluebat.

Comment: Did you put a resistor between the Arduino and the gate of the mosfet?

Comment: Yes, 220 ohms for good measure. I know the 2N7000 doesn't surge. I checked the MOSFETs, and all LED channels (R, G, B) work. It's just the nano that's dead.

Comment: You could try reflashing the boot loader using a separate Arduino. Have you measured the voltage of the power supply? Some are only 12V when under load, and can go as high as e.g. 18V when there is no or minimal load.

Comment: Also try measuring the 5V pin when you connect the 12v to Vin. It could be that the voltage regulator is broken.

Comment: I see a 5V signal on the 5V pin, but the program in flash is not running as far as I can tell. The PWM pins send out random values, and turning the potentiometer is not affecting these values. The power supply is at 12V, both unloaded and loaded. I use one of these for a small 10W drill. I'll look into flashing it on the RXD/TXD pins first, then I'll try reflashing the bootloader. Thanks. If you post the last comment below as an answer, I'll close this question.

Comment: Dyd you try to flash in a simple Blink using the onboard LED? You should go very basic when things start to fail like that. Also, disconnect the 12V power supply and power your nano from USB only when running this simple test: the voltage regulator should not be part of the circuit when powered from USB and you can start factoring things out.

Comment: Yes, I did that - the device is not responding. Rxd/Txd pins are dead as well. I'm putting this down to overheating voltage regulator inside an already toasty-hot closed compartment.